# list indices must be integers or slices, not str.x

Tags: python, list, pandas

I am having error message when I try to calculate the rolling average values using Pandas.
**Error:**

```
list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Could not figure out how to solve it. Can anyone suggest? Thank you.

```
for file in filename_day:
    df = pd.read_csv(path_day + file)
    Data_length=len(df)-1
    ma_data=[]
    ma_list=[5,10,20,30,60]
    for ma in ma_list:
        ma_data['MA_' + str(ma)] = pd.rolling_mean(df['close'], window=ma)
        print(ma_data)
    df.to_csv('C:/20180424_DD/MA/'+file)
```

Comment: Looks like you need `ma_data=[]` to be `ma_data={}`(Dictionary)

Comment: Is this your code? Can you explain what each line is doing and why?

Comment: @Frank, see this when you have you have time [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Error is thrown from this line:

```
ma_data['MA_' + str(ma)] = pd.rolling_mean(df['close'], window=ma)
```

As you have already declared `ma_data` as `list` --> `ma_data=[]`. But in above code you are trying to create a `key` like `'MA_' + str(ma)` in a `ma_data`, which is a `list`.

What you need is a dictionary here:

```
ma_data = {}
```

Comment: great, would you like to accept the answer as well?

Answer (score 0):

As akshat said the error is in that row. If you want a `list` instead of `dictionary`, modify you code in this way:

```
for ma in ma_list:
    df['MA_' + str(ma)] = pd.rolling_mean(df['close'], window=ma)
    ma_data.append(df['MA_' + str(ma)])
```

In general `pd.rolling_mean`is deprecated. You may think to use:

```
df['MA_' + str(ma)] = df['close'].rolling(window=ma).mean()
```

instead.